# VBA Macro filtering cells, how do I handle "No cells were found" error

Tags: excel, vba

I've code that moves all non-blank cells on a worksheet to the first available blank cell in their row.

Instead of the code running against the full sheet I would like it to ignore Column A & B and Rows 1, 2, and 3.

To do this I change `.Range(.Cells(1, 1)` to `.Range(.Cells(4, 3)` which works perfectly on fresh excel sheets with test data entered. This test data is just randomly scattered data entered into various cells.

When I run the code on my actual worksheet `Set delrng = .Rows(rw).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` comes up with the error `Run-time error '1004': No cells were found.` and fails to execute anything.

Googling is bringing up a few topics on error handling `No Cells were found` but I don't think just removing the error helps me here.

Thank you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Shift_Left()

Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long, delrng As Range

With Worksheets("Application Maturity Tracker")
    lr = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
    lc = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

    With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, lc))
        For rw = 1 To .Rows.Count
            Set delrng = .Rows(rw).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            If Not delrng Is Nothing Then
                delrng.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            End If
        Next rw

    End With

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I think probably what you found when you googled is what you need. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: From my granted low level of knowledge it looked like they revolved around skipping over the error rather than resolving. I'm not sure why this is even triggering in the first place.

Comment: This is one of the rare cases when it's acceptable (not to mention necessary) to skip over the error. As the message suggests it errors because there are no blank cells.

Comment: You should have `Set delrng = .Rows(rw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells.`

Comment: Same error as before with that adjustment (unsure if that's expected and just the correct syntax). Does sticking `On Error Resume Next` before `Set delrng = .Rows(rw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells` seem sensible? Thank you for the help

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you @SJR. If you wanna stick that as an answer I'll flag it. Thank you as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to skip over the error (not usually recommended but unavoidable here). Remember to re-set the error checking once that line has executed.

```
With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, lc))
    For rw = 1 To .Rows.Count
        On Error Resume Next
        Set delrng = .Rows(rw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not delrng Is Nothing Then
            delrng.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Next rw

End With
```

Comment: Thanks kindly as always @SJR

Comment: It's my pleasure.